# How to change Vue project build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

The structure of produced files when we run **npm run build** in Vue app are like below:

[image]

The platform where I want to deploy this project requires me to put all files within the root, so it should be like below structure:

[image]

Can anybody show me how to tweak the build process so I can get what is required? I did check on how to customized webpack in [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration), but it doesn't show me how to custom build destination folder for css, js and image files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of vue-cli did you use to setup your project?

Comment: Vue-cli ver 3.12.1

Comment: Can anybody help?.. what I do currently is moving all files manually and updates the generated index.html